# maclaurin series for function undefined at a point

Tags: taylor-expansion

Say i want a power series for a function such as $$\frac{(2x+2)(x)}{(2x)(3x+1)}$$ at $x=0$.
How would one go about this? I have acquired the second, third and fourth terms, but am struggling getting the first term since f(0) is undefined.

Can one just assume that for very small $x%$, i.e $\lambda << 1$ then $ f(\lambda)\approx 1$ hence the series takes the form 1+....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first term is the limit at the point.

We get $$\frac{(2x+2)(x)}{(2x)(3x+1)}=\frac{x+1}{3x+1}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3x+1}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n3^nx^n$$

Comment: Inst the limit of this function $$\frac{2x^2}{6x^2} \rightarrow \frac{1}{3} $$

Comment: @MathsPro The limit at the point $x=0$ is $1$.

Comment: I see that it should be 1, since as i said for values close to 0 the answer is 1, however how do i prove this

Comment: The first equality above gives you a function that is equal to your function at all points near $x=0$. The new function $$\frac{x+1}{3x+1}$$ is continuous at $x=0$. Therefore, taking the limit is the same as evaluating at the point. We get $$\frac{0+1}{3\times 0+1}=1$$.

Comment: @MathsPro Aternatively, you can do as I did in my answer. Compute the series. By uniqueness of power series this is the one and its first term is $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand! Would it not have been simpler for me just to rewrite my function as $\frac{x+1}{3x+1}$ and just find the power series of this since it is defined at f(0)

Comment: @MathsPro That is what is happening in this answer.

Comment: Great stuff! I fully understand

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you might factor a 2 out of the first factor of the top, and then cancel $2x$ on top and bottom. That gets you a new function $x/(3x+1)$ that equals yours almost everywhere, hence they have the same MacLaurin series. The series for YOUR function at 0 isn't really well-defined, but if it were, it'd have to be the series for mine...

Comment: I see that this would work however is there not just a general method of getting the first term without comparison to other functions

Comment: That depends on your definition of "Maclaurin series"; my favorite definition doesn't allow for a Maclaurin series except at points where the function is infinitely differentiable (hence, at the very least, points where it's *defined*). If there's another function $g$ that's infinitely differentiable and matches yours except at the selected point, you *could* use the series for $g$...which is what I did. So my method really IS a general method. The fact that $g = f$ except at $0$ and $g$ is smooth means that $g(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} g(x) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$, so that gives the degree $0$ term.